# Need help rescuing a RH virtual server - shell command to fix mistake?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a VM which runs one of our primary applications. Prior to making a rather heavy handed change, I made two lines of backup. First, I took a VM snapshot. Second, I ran a recursive `sed` command through the whole system to replace text in files, and create backups as it went. It wasn't until after I ran this that I realized how extensive the change was. Here's what I ran:

```
find / -type f -print0|xargs -0 sed -i.matthew05012013 's/oldtext/newtext/g'
```

I attempted to revert the snapshot, but ended up removing it instead, which committed all of the changes (Because ESX nomenclature is gosh darn confusing with snapshots). So, my last line of defense is recursively going through the system, and renaming anything with the .matthew05012013 extension added to the same filename, without the extension, overwriting whatever is there.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to best execute this? By hand won't work, there are several thousand files which have been modified thorough the system.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly graceful the following should do the trick:

```
for modfile in `find <dir> -name "*.matthew05012013"`; do
  realfile=`echo $modfile | sed 's/.matthew05012013//'`
  cp $modfile $realfile
done
```

I did it to a test directory:

```
$ find /tmp/deleteme/
/tmp/deleteme/
/tmp/deleteme/1
/tmp/deleteme/1/filea
/tmp/deleteme/1/fileb
/tmp/deleteme/1/filec
/tmp/deleteme/1/filed
/tmp/deleteme/1/fileb.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/1/filed.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/2
/tmp/deleteme/2/filea
/tmp/deleteme/2/fileb
/tmp/deleteme/2/filec
/tmp/deleteme/2/filed
/tmp/deleteme/2/fileb.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/2/filed.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/3
/tmp/deleteme/3/filea
/tmp/deleteme/3/fileb
/tmp/deleteme/3/filec
/tmp/deleteme/3/filed
/tmp/deleteme/3/fileb.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/3/filed.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/4
/tmp/deleteme/4/filea
/tmp/deleteme/4/fileb
/tmp/deleteme/4/filec
/tmp/deleteme/4/filed
/tmp/deleteme/4/fileb.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/4/filed.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/5
/tmp/deleteme/5/filea
/tmp/deleteme/5/fileb
/tmp/deleteme/5/filec
/tmp/deleteme/5/filed
/tmp/deleteme/5/fileb.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/5/filed.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/6
/tmp/deleteme/6/filea
/tmp/deleteme/6/fileb
/tmp/deleteme/6/filec
/tmp/deleteme/6/filed
/tmp/deleteme/6/fileb.matthew05012013
/tmp/deleteme/6/filed.matthew05012013

$ for modfile in `find /tmp/deleteme -name "*.matthew05012013"`; do 
    realfile=`echo $modfile | sed 's/.matthew05012013//'`
    echo "cp $modfile $realfile"
    done

cp /tmp/deleteme/1/fileb.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/1/fileb
cp /tmp/deleteme/1/filed.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/1/filed
cp /tmp/deleteme/2/fileb.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/2/fileb
cp /tmp/deleteme/2/filed.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/2/filed
cp /tmp/deleteme/3/fileb.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/3/fileb
cp /tmp/deleteme/3/filed.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/3/filed
cp /tmp/deleteme/4/fileb.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/4/fileb
cp /tmp/deleteme/4/filed.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/4/filed
cp /tmp/deleteme/5/fileb.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/5/fileb
cp /tmp/deleteme/5/filed.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/5/filed
cp /tmp/deleteme/6/fileb.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/6/fileb
cp /tmp/deleteme/6/filed.matthew05012013 /tmp/deleteme/6/filed
```

Obviously this has the same heavy handed approach as you mentioned before and if I were to do it in production, I would probably echo out the cp commands (as shown in my test) and send them to a file to review.  Then simply execute them after I have verified that everything looks right.   Just be sure that the string you look for (.matthew05012013 in the example) is unique enough so that it doesn't match something else.  And replace the 'cp' with a 'mv' or whatever other command floats your boat.

I would also recommend doing another snapshot BEFORE doing this change though just in case something further goes wrong you don't have to try to clean up an additional mess.

Also take care in preserving permissions during this change.  Check the 'cp' manpage to add arguments for preserving permissions or implement a specific umask before executing this.  You can quickly get in hot water when you have thousands of files with permissions that don't allow your application to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -type f -name '*.matthew05012013' -print0 | \
  xargs -0 rename .matthew05012013 ""
```

This would fail if there are files with ".matthew05012013" occurring twice in the name, once at the end. This is probably not the case and could be prevented by using another tool like mmv or a simple shell script.